# Find number of days that intersect a given date range in a table of date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find the total number of days in a date range that overlap a table of date ranges.

For example, I have 7 days between 2 dates in the table below. I want to find the days between between them that also fall this date range: 2019-08-01 to 2019-08-30.

It should return 1 day.

This is the data source query:

```
SELECT LeaveId, UserId, StartDate, EndDate, Days
FROM TblLeaveRequest
WHERE UserId = 218
```

```
LeaveID     UserID      StartDate               EndDate                 Days
----------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------
22484       218         2019-07-26 00:00:00.000 2019-08-01 00:00:00.000 7
```

Comment: What if your data makes this not possible, e.g. what if `2019-07-26` has two days worth of data?

Comment: Provide some sample data, expected output

Comment: Will your date range always be a month?  That would be easier and you wouldn't have to specify start and end dates for the range to compare against.

Comment: This can be answer in so many ways depending upon what your input look like.Take effort to explain the matter to get best answer.What is your input like ? What to doyou pass in Proc.`This is the data source query` onwards thing are useless.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this might help you:

```
--create the table
SELECT 
    22484 LeaveID, 
    218 UserID, 
    CONVERT(DATETIME,'7/26/2019') StartDate, 
    CONVERT(DATETIME,'8/1/2019') EndDate, 
    7 Days
INTO #TblLeaveRequest

--Range Paramters
DECLARE @StartRange AS DATETIME = '8/1/2019'
DECLARE @EndRange AS DATETIME = '8/30/2019'

--Find sum of days between StartDate and EndDate that intersect the range paramters
--for UserId=218
SELECT 
    SUM(
    DATEDIFF(
        DAY
        ,CASE WHEN @StartRange < StartDate THEN StartDate ELSE @StartRange END
        ,DATEADD(DAY, 1, CASE WHEN @EndRange > EndDate THEN EndDate ELSE @EndRange END)
        )
    ) TotalDays
from #TblLeaveRequest
where UserId=218
```

This assumes that no start dates are greater than end dates.  It also assumes that the range parameters always intersect some portion of the range in the table.

If the parameter ranges might not intersect then you'll have to eliminate those cases by excluding negative days:

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN Days < 0 THEN 0 ELSE Days END ) TotalDays
FROM
(
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(
        DAY
        ,CASE WHEN @StartRange < StartDate THEN StartDate ELSE @StartRange END
        ,DATEADD(DAY, 1, CASE WHEN @EndRange > EndDate THEN EndDate ELSE @EndRange END)
        ) Days
from #TblLeaveRequest
where UserId=218
) TotalDays
```

Comment: If some of the rows in the table have intervals that do not intersect with the given range, then `DATEDIFF` in your query would return negative value that would be added to the total by `SUM`. Maybe this is not the result that @rinkuChoudhary wants to see.

Comment: Good point... I've added a query to the answer that anticipates that case.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your problem correctly, you have two ranges of dates and you are looking for the number of days in the intersection.

Considering a Gant chart:

```
Start_1 .................... End_1
                 Start_2 .......................End_2
```

If you can create a table structure like

```
LeaveID     UserID      StartDate_1  EndDate_1  StartDate_2  EndDate_2 
----------- ----------- ----------   ---------  ----------   ---------
22484       218         2019-07-26  2019-08-01  2019-08-01   2019-08-30
```

You can determine the number of days by

```
select 
 leaveID
 , UserID
 ,case 
      when StartDate_2 <= EndDate_1 then datediff(day,StartDate_2,EndDate_1) + 1
      else 0
      end as delta_days_intersection
from table
```

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use a numbers (Tally) table to count the number of days:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/113f9/16)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE LeaveRequest
(
  LeaveId Int,
  UserId Int,
  StartDate Date,
  EndDate Date,
  Days Int
)

Insert Into LeaveRequest
VALUES
(22484, 218, '2019-07-26','2019-08-01', 7)
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @StartDate Date = '2019-08-01'
DECLARE @EndDate Date = '2019-08-30'
;WITH Tally
AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORdER By Numbers.Num) AS Num
  FROM
  (
    Values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)
  )Numbers(Num)
  Cross APPLY
  (
    Values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)
  )Numbers2(Num2)
)
SELECT COUNT(DATEADD(d, Num -1, StartDate)) As NumberOfDays
FROM LeaveRequest
CROSS APPLY Tally
WHERE  DATEADD(d, Num -1, StartDate) <= EndDate AND
DATEADD(d, Num -1, StartDate) >= @StartDate AND
DATEADD(d, Num -1, StartDate) <= @EndDate
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/113f9/16/0)**:

```
| NumberOfDays |
|--------------|
|            1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #LeaveRequest
(
  LeaveId Int,
  UserId Int,
  StartDate Date,
  EndDate Date,
  Days Int
)

Insert Into #LeaveRequest
VALUES
(22484, 218, '2019-07-26','2019-08-01', 7)

Declare @FromDate datetime='2019-08-01' 
declare @ToDate datetime='2019-08-30'



;With CTE as
(
select top (DATEDIFF(day,@FromDate,@ToDate)+1) 
DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select null))-1,@FromDate) DT
from sys.objects
)

select * from #LeaveRequest LR
cross apply(select count(*)IntersectingDays 
from CTE c where dt between lr.StartDate and lr.EndDate)ca

--or
--select lr.*,c.* 
from  CTE c 
--cross apply
(select lr.* from #LeaveRequest LR 
where c.DT between lr.StartDate and lr.EndDate)lr

drop table #LeaveRequest
```

Better create one Calendar table which will always help you in other queries also.

```
create table CalendarDate(Dates DateTime primary key)
insert into CalendarDate WITH (TABLOCK)  (Dates)
select top (1000000) 
DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select null))-1,'1970-01-01') DT
from sys.objects
```

Then inside CTE write this,

```
select top (DATEDIFF(day,@FromDate,@ToDate)+1) Dates from CalendarDate
where Dates between @FromDate and @ToDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @FromDate datetime = '2019-08-01' 
DECLARE @ToDate datetime = '2019-08-30'

SELECT
    IIF(@FromDate <= EndDate AND @ToDate >= StartDate,
        DATEDIFF(day,
            IIF(StartDate > @FromDate, StartDate, @FromDate),
            IIF(EndDate < @ToDate, EndDate, @ToDate)
        ),
    0) AS overlapping_days
FROM TblLeaveRequest;
```